# Scroll Views in storyboarding iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I'm trying to set up a scrollView in an app using storyboarding. I have done everything correctly but the scrollview won't scroll in simulator or on iPhone.

```
MoreViewController.h
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *moreScroll;

MoreViewController.m
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [moreScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [moreScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1220, 354)];
}
```

I have connected the scrollView to the files owner, can someone help please

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you actually added content to the scrollview?

Comment: Yes I have using storyboarding

Comment: Yes I am, does it make a difference if i was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an scroll view’s scroller style sets the style of both the horizontal and vertical scrollers. If the scroll view subsequently creates or is assigned a new horizontal or vertical scroller, they will be assigned the same scroller style that was assigned to the scroll view..

You should be if you add this lines  in your code:

```
 This line in .h file

 @interface Shout_RouteView : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> 
 {

  }

 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollViewMain;


 This lines copy in .m file 
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    scrollViewMain.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 815);
    [scrollViewMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1040)];
}else {
    scrollViewMain.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370);
    [scrollViewMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 510)];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With autolayout is there a new method `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Here is a quick info:
Notifies the view controller that its view just laid out its subviews.
When a view’s bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews. Your view controller can override this method to make changes after the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this method does nothing.

You should be fine if you add this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubViews];
    [moreScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1220, 354)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to pust the content setting code into the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method. Its always best not attempt changing UI features before it is ready for display.